# Error in Calling Web service Through SSL (java)

Tags: java, ssl

java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)

Facing above error while calling web-server from SSL, but when I restart tomcat it start working fine for a while. Do some need full ASAP.

Comment: More on the stack trace and the general context of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up a proper certificate configuration. Here you have pdf explaining how http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/content/Exam-Objectives-5.pdf

Good luck

Comment: thank u.                                                         actually it was configure in same way mention in pdf and as i written it was working fine for while... but dont know how to fix this issue paramnently

Comment: actually my issue is still same. when i restart tomcat its working fine and after few hour its start showing error.